# How do i append ".php" extension in href inside my while loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a while loop and its working properly, i am new to php and cannot figure out how to append the .php extention in the href inside php.
This is my loop:

```
while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                  echo"<tr>
                    <td><a href=". $get['title'] ." target=\"_blank\">".$get['title']."</a></td>
                    <td>".$get['info']."</td>
                    <td>".$get['author']."</td>
                    <td>".$get['price']."</td>
                    <td><a href='dwn.php?rn=$get[id]' target=\"_blank\">Download</a></td>
                  </tr>";
                }
```

I want to add . php extention inside the href in the first  tag , i thought it would be something like this :

```
<td><a href=" . $get['title'] . '.php'" target=\"_blank\">".$get['title']."</a></td>
```

But ofcourse this doest work, So please help me what should i do
Thanks in advance and Sorry for Bad English.

Comment: Look at your own example a few lines down, where you have `dwn.php?rn=` at the beginning of the `href`. Adding `.php` at the end of it is no different.

Comment: `target=\"_blank\"` would be better and more readable as : `target='_blank'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an very easy solution while messing with the code.

Turns out i just had to contain `". $get['title'] ."` inside Single apostrophe(''), Like this:

```
<td><a href='". $get['title'] .".php' target=\"_blank\">".$get['title']."</a></td>
```

It works and the problem is Solved.

Comment: You would do well to move away from `mysqli_fetch_assoc` line of functions and [**focus on PDO PHP functions**](https://phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension) going forwards.

Answer (score 0):

you missed a poi after `.php` to concatenate

```
while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                  echo"<tr>
                    <td><a href='". $get['title'] .'.php'."' target=\"_blank\">".$get['title']."</a></td>
                    <td>".$get['info']."</td>
                    <td>".$get['author']."</td>
                    <td>".$get['price']."</td>
                    <td><a href='dwn.php?rn=$get[id]' target=\"_blank\">Download</a></td>
                  </tr>";
                }
```

I suggest you to take a look to `printf` for this type of string templating

```
while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                  printf("<tr>
                    <td><a href='%s.php' target=\"_blank\">%s</a></td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td><a href='dwn.php?rn=%d' target=\"_blank\">Download</a></td>
                  </tr>", 
                 $get['title'],
                 $get['title'],
                 $get['info'],
                 $get['author'],
                 $get['price'],
                 $get['id']
                 );
                }
```

Comment: `'". $get['title'] .'.php'."'` this makes no sense.

Comment: `I suggest you to take a look to printf` perhaps **edit** your answer and say ***WHY*** you suggest this approach?